# How to make a generic purge procedure with param table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm getting mad while trying to make a generic purge procedure.

I have a param table (`PURGE_PARAM_TABLE`) built this way :

[image]

And a procedure which store data into a hist table and delete it from the current table.
I want that procedure to be generic and cleaning these two tables both.

So for each line of the param table, the procedure fetch the table to purge (`TABLENAME`) which can be whether the current table or its associated historical table (`MYTABLENAME_HIST`).

You can understand that there are different `RETENTION_DAYS` by table type.
Given that the `TABLENAME` is a parameter I have to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statements, so here is the procedure :

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE MY_PURGE AS
CURSOR flows IS
  SELECT * FROM PURGE_PARAM_TABLE;
BEGIN
  FOR f IN flows LOOP
    IF f.RETENTION_DAYS IS NULL THEN
      RETURN;
    END IF;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || f.TABLENAME || '_HIST
      SELECT * FROM ' || f.TABLENAME || ' WHERE DATE_DEB < TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('|| SYSDATE - f.RETENTION_DAYS ||', ''yyyy/mm/dd''), ''yyyy/mm/dd'')
      AND NAME = '|| f.FLOW ||' AND APPLI = '|| f.APPLICATION;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || f.TABLENAME || ' WHERE DATE_DEB < TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('|| SYSDATE - f.RETENTION_DAYS ||', ''yyyy/mm/dd''), ''yyyy/mm/dd'')
      AND NAME = '|| f.FLOW ||' AND APPLI = '|| f.APPLICATION;

    -- If it is a historical table
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(f.TABLENAME, '+_HIST$') THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || f.TABLENAME || ' WHERE DATE_DEB < TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('|| SYSDATE - f.RETENTION_DAYS ||', ''yyyy/mm/dd''), ''yyyy/mm/dd'')
      AND NAME = '|| f.FLOW ||' AND APPLI = '|| f.APPLICATION;
    END IF;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE PURGE_PARAM_TABLE SET LAST_PURGE_DATE = SYSDATE, 
      FIRST_ROW_DATE = (SELECT MIN(DATE_DEB) FROM ' || f.TABLENAME || ' 
                        WHERE NAME = '|| f.FLOW ||' AND APPLI = '|| f.APPLICATION ||')
      WHERE APPLICATION = '|| f.APPLICATION ||' AND FLOW = '|| f.FLOW;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The problem is that sqldeveloper throws me an error :

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
>   ORA-06512: at "MONITOR.ACQDBRTR_PURGE", line 10

Line 10 corresponding to the first `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and I'm stuck with it.

Hope you can help !

Comment: My humble advice will be before straight going for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE first try to dbms_output the statement which is getting formed dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

First off, why not put a where clause in your cursor to select only the records that have a not null retention_days? You can skip the if inside the loop.
Secondly you can do without the to_date(to_char.
And it gets even better when you use bind variables

Example using your first statement only:

```
create or replace procedure my_purge as

    l_statement varchar2(32767);

   cursor flows is
      select *
        from purge_param_table
       where retention_days is not null;
begin
   for f in flows
   loop

      l_statement:= 'INSERT INTO ' || f.tablename || '_HIST
                            SELECT *
                            FROM ' || f.tablename || '
                            WHERE DATE_DEB <  :my_date
                            AND NAME = :flow
                            AND APPLI = :application';

      execute immediate l_statement using (sysdate - f.retention_days), f.flow, f.application;

   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it !

@Avrajit Roy good advice, thanks
It helped me finding where I was wrong.

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || f.TABLENAME || '_HIST
   SELECT * FROM ' || f.TABLENAME || ' WHERE DATE_DEB < '''|| SYSDATE || '''-' || f.RETENTION_DAYS ||' AND NAME = '''|| f.FLOW ||''' AND APPLI = '''|| f.APPLICATION ||'''';`

Here is the good way to write it.

(Values must be between single quotes)

Thank you for your time !